# Pro*C dynamic queries for `select`s with `in` conditions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

It's usually strongly recommended to avoid Pro*C dynamic queries as much as possible, but sometimes I don't know when I'm under a situation where I can actually avoid them or not. A common use case of mine is when I have queries with `in` where clauses like `col in (n1, n2, n...)`, where the size and values of such `n`-list is not known at compile time.

The only way I know to avoid such dynamic query is by changing the `in` condition to `col = :var` and apply an iterative fetching, where `var` iterates over the `n`-list.

Comparing the two methods, woudn't the dynamic query be more efficient than the recursive fetching? Since I'm feeding the query with a constant list of values, if `col` is not indexed, I'm forcing a `FULL TABLE SCAN` only once to collect all the values (take in mind that there could be `order by` and `row_number` clauses with partitions involved in the query so a full table scan is not avoidable), while by using a cursor I'm applying a `FULL TABLE SCAN` at each iteration.

Am I right on this? Am I still right when `col` is indexed, that the dynamic query will still be more efficient? Which other alternatives do I have?

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. I recommend you ask a very specific question regarding the resource consumption and elapsed time for a given execution plan for a statement your code executes. To do that, you can use extended SQL trace which is sometimes referred to as event 10046. Avoiding dynamic queries is the wrong goal. Eliminating waste is a more suitable goal. Eliminating waste does not mean you have to throw away any tool (e.g. dynamic query).

Comment: Yes, in your situation there would be a significant performance penalty for doing multiple `col = :var` queries compared to one `col in (..)` query. Instead of going down the simple dynamic query route though, you could try seeing if you can use array binds (I'm not sure if it's possible with pro*c) then you'd end up with one static query that can use an in list. Or you could limit the amount of queries you'd be generating by only using certain numbers of elements in these lists-https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/13/when-using-bind-variables-is-not-enough-dynamic-in-lists/ shows this off (in java)

Comment: @AndrewSayer I've tried to find examples of using array of values as input for select statements in pro*c files without success so far.

Comment: store the values for the IN clause in a temporary table, and use that instead of separate values

Comment: @OldProgrammer I haven't test that, but using `with aux_table as (select * from table (sys.ocdinumberlist(...))) select my_cols from aux_table, blablabla` the performance drops a lot since the list is no longer a constant expression, and the plan is executed by a joining tables instead of doing a simple rows-wise check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hiearchical query as follows:

```
Col in (Select regexp_substr(:var,'[^,]+',1,level) 
          from dual 
        Connect by regexp_substr(:var,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null)
```